# inline C# code inside aspx page is giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources

So basically i have a asp.net project where in the aspx page inside HTML code i use csharp annotation to put c# code.

So when i try to put resource code inside it gives me error. check the example below.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" data-toggle="tab" href="#Groups" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,rs_test %>" ID="link_Groups" CssClass="hub_mediumFont" />
```

in this line we can see the c# code is written inside a double quotation and this works fine but as soon as i try to use C# outside a double quotation it does not work. for example

```
<span><%$ Resources:Resource,rs_test %></span>
```

this does not work. i event tried <%:....%> but its till the same.

Can anyone give me an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Google "DataBinding Expression". That is what you need.

Comment: Data bind is for database i think (all the examples with database in google) but i need it from the resource files. as i said one format is working good when its inside " " but outside " " like <Span>text from resource file</span> is not working, any idea?

Comment: @PratikSahaJoy does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is not about double quotation. From [Working with Resources in Web Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms227427%28v%3dvs.140%29#working-with-resources-in-web-pages):

> After you create resource files, you can use them in ASP.NET Web
>   pages. You typically use resources to fill the property values of
>   controls on the page. For example, you might use resources to set the
>   Text property of a Button control, instead of hard-coding the property
>   to a specific string.

So you can not use `Resources` directly for static string, you can put resource in asp.net controls like `Label` instead:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,rs_test %>" />
```

Or you can use `Localize` control to static text. From [Localizing Static Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms227427%28v%3dvs.140%29#localizing-static-text):

> If a page includes static text, you can use ASP.NET localization by
>   including it in a Localize control, and then using explicit
>   localization to set the static text. The Localize control renders no
>   markup; its only function is to act as a placeholder for localized
>   text.

```
<asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,rs_test %>" />
```